# How do I get a Patent Scrutinizer?

Tags: fallen-london

I am working on my Heart's Desire, and need a Patent Scrutinizer. It said I could get one using my Luminosity items, but I can't seem to figure it out.

How do I get the Patent Scrutinizer?

Answer (score 5):

I think I simply bought mine from the Bazaar, way back then. Nowadays, it appears that the Carrow's Steel has some for 28.80 echoes.

According to the wiki, the other way involves grinding and requires converting Luminosity items indeed: Lamplighter Beeswax -> Phosphorescent Scarab -> Memories of Light -> Mourning Candles -> Patent Scrutinizers.

Consider that you will need:

- 50 Phosphorescent Scarabs -> 10 Memories of Light
- 50 Memories of Light -> 10 Mourning Candles
- 25 Mourning Candles -> 5 Patent Scrutinizers

Also, these actions require a connection to the Revolutionaries (up to level 6 for the last step) and it will drop at every conversion, possibly requiring more grinding elsewhere to bring it back up.

Comment: When I converted Memories of Light, I got Zee-Ztories....

Comment: Memories of Light can be converted into two different things: Mourning Candles and Zee-Ztories. Read the available actions on the Memories of Light very carefully, so you pick the top one instead of the bottom one. Once you get to level-3 items, there isn't a "mass convert" action; there's just one action to convert to a level-4 item, and another one to convert to a different level-3 item. See http://echobazaar.wikidot.com/item-conversions